# AIX and winbind users, works fine all except for:""I have no name!"

Tags: aix, winbind

I want winbind auth in AIX. 
Samba works fine:

```
wbinfo -g
cert publishers
dnsadmins
domain guests
group policy creator owners
domain computers
allowed rodc password replication group
domain controllers
domain users
ras and ias servers
denied rodc password replication group
read-only domain controllers
domain admins
enterprise read-only domain controllers
schema admins
enterprise admins
dnsupdateproxy
```

Also wbinfo -i user works

```
wbinfo -i myuser
myuser:*:10003:10000::/home/myuser:/opt/freeware/bin/bash
```

I have configured the auth in this way
i modify the file /etc/security/users in this way

```
    system = "compat or WINBIND"
```

I have modified also /usr/lib/security/methods.cfg

```
WINBIND:
        program = /opt/freeware/lib/WINBIND.so
        program_64 = /opt/freeware/lib/WINBIND.so

NIS:
        program = /usr/lib/security/NIS
        program_64 = /usr/lib/security/NIS_64

DCE:
        program = /usr/lib/security/DCE
```

All commands works(ssh,lsuser,id,etc) 
but in the shell prompt I get

for non winbind user

```
nonwinbinduser@aix:~$
```

for winbind user

```
I have no name!@aix:~$
```

What I miss?

Comment: How is PS1 defined? Is it `$(whoami)` or some shell escape character?

Comment: Is not a PS1 problem, the user can login, but his uid cannot be translated

Comment: Interesting; I was mainly trying to figure out what command was being executed (or system call being called) that corresponded to the username or `I have no name!` as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: The logins commands,as ssh,su,telnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
The configuration is correct.
But AIX is a 64bit os(at least my system boot with 64bit kernel, and Samba is compiled only for 32bit(sic!)
So the solution is to find a Samba suite compiled for Aix 64bit, otherwise uid cannot be translated unless you run Aix with 32bit kernel.

the proof

```
ls32 -ld /home/myuser/
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser     domain u       4096 25 nov 03.07 /home/myuser/


ls -ld /home/myuser/
drwxr-xr-x 3 10003 10000 4096 nov 25 03:07 /home/myuser//
```

another proof

```
id_32 anotheruser
uid=10005(anotheruser) gid=10016(domain users) groups=10016(domain users)

id_64 anotheruser
id_64: ‘anotheruser’: no such user

id anotheruser
id_64: ‘anotheruser’: no such user
```